# rendering string as html in dropdown menu

Tags: reactjs

I am trying the following code to make one of the options `Volvo2` but what I keep getting `Volvo [object Object]`. I couldn't quite figure out how to make `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` work either. Is there a way to achieve it?

In my actual app, all text (`Volvo<sup>2</sup>`, `Saab`, etc) would come as a string and could have `<sup>`, `<sub>`, or some other tag.

```
import React from "react";

export default function DropDown(props) {
  return (
    <select>
      <option value="volvo">
        Volvo<sup>2</sup>
      </option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
  );
}
```

Comment: Note that html `<option>` only allows text content, not child elements

Answer (score 1):

This is not a react specific problem but rather a general select-option problem. This can be solved by using unicode like this:

```
Volvo&#178;
```

So you could use a function which will parse the sub and sup tags to the respective unicode.

Comment: I can't know in advance what the unicode is going to be.

Comment: I don't know if there is a way to make select/option render html tags but an alternative could be to use another HTML element which will act like a dropdown. In there you can freely render it.

Answer (score 1):

The content of `option` tag can only be text. You can use:

```
<option value="volvo">
    Volvo&sup2;
</option>
```